# What does immersed mean in this context?

Tags: differential-geometry

In a paper, I am reading it states: If $M$ is immersed by an analytic map $\xi = (\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n): U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined on a ball $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, ...

Can someone explain me what does "immersed" mean here? When I look it up online, it seems that immersion means it is a map of manifolds whose induced map of tangent spaces are injective... But I'm not sure what that means in this context...

Does it mean the matrix $[\partial \xi_i/\partial x_j]$ has full rank at every point on $U$?

Comment: $\xi:U\to\mathbb R^n$ is an immersion if the induced map on tangent spaces $d_p\xi:T_pU\to T_{\xi(p)}\mathbb R^n$ is injective ($U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$, so it'a also a manifold). Since the differential map is linear, the representative matrix respect to the standard basis $\mathcal B=\{\partial x^j\}_{j=1}^d$ of $T_pU$ is such that $\text{rank} M_{\mathcal B}(d_pf)=\dim(U)$.

Comment: Intuitively, an immersion means the embedding is smooth. For example, an ellipsoid is an immersion of the sphere, but the surface of a cube is not, even though topologically they are the same.

Comment: @Vajra By $d_p f$ this means the Jacobian matrix $[\partial \xi_i/ \partial x_j]$ at $p$?

Comment: Yes it's a like linear algebra problem